# May the certificate root store contain non-self-signed certificates?

Tags: security, ssl, cryptography, certificate, ssl-certificate

May the root store contain non-self-signed certificates, i.e. the issuer and subject are different?

If so, will certificate chain validations return “success” upon encountering a non-self-signed certificate in the root store, or will the validation continue in the root store until either a self-signed certificate (“success”) or none (“fail”) is encountered?

I suspect this behavior is implementation dependent, but I can’t find any reference.

Comment: "root store" tends to be used as a generic description. Which specific platform are you interested in?

Comment: Windows, Linux, and Firefox, etc.

Answer (score -1):

A root as defined in [RFC5280, Section 3.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280#section-3.2):

> ```
>   (a)  Internet Policy Registration Authority (IPRA):  This
>       authority, operated under the auspices of the Internet
>       Society, acts as the root of the PEM certification hierarchy
>       at level 1.  It issues certificates only for the next level
>       of authorities, PCAs.  All certification paths start with the
>       IPRA.
> ```

Therefore, a "root store", even if it is a generic, non-specified, description (as President James K. Polk pointed out in his comment), should **only contain root CA certificates**, which means they have signed themselves.

If you do there might be unwanted side effects...

**On Windows this breaks MutualTLS with Internet Information Services (IIS)**
This is also *not specified by the RFC* but the issue is documented as Cause 2 here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/http-403-forbidden-access-website

Comment: Can you elaborate? Is it part of some RFC spec?